# Is there a way to use a real-world programming language in a MW-template?

Tags: templates, mediawiki

Since MW-templates tend to get very obfuscated when using the parserfunctions-extension and useless without it, I am curious if there is any extension that would me allow to write templates in a realworld scripting language like PHP, Ruby, Perl, any other? I would preffer Ruby, but if it would even be possible I would be glad about everything else that looks cleaner than parserfunctions...

Of course, whatever scripting language is used, it should really be sandboxed for security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no production-ready extension that would let you do that. [Work on adding the Lua language to MediaWiki has started](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLua), but it's currently in a very early phase, so I don't think it would be a good idea to use it.

Comment: This is a good starting point, but sadly it does not allow access to the properties defined by SMW :( I'll take a look into the code, if some enhencements are possible...